# jQuery each() first iteration is wrong, the rest are correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So, I'm creating a piece of code so the images in my div are automatically centered and adjusted, so they fit in a squared box.

Currently, I've managed to do so, but, something is wrong with the first iteration, because I get the wrong result, let me show you the code.

```js
// news section height calculator
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.news-picture').find('img').each(function () {
            
            var screenImage = $(this);
            var theImage = new Image();
            theImage.src = screenImage.attr("src");

// Get accurate measurements from that.
            var imageWidth = theImage.width;
            var imageHeight = theImage.height; 
            
            var $imgClass = (imageWidth / imageHeight);  
            var $imgPos = -((imageWidth - $(window).width()) / 2);
            console.log(imageWidth);    
            console.log($(window).width());  
            
            if ($imgClass >= 1) {
                $(this).addClass('wide').css("left" , $imgPos);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('tall');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
                    <div class="news-picture">
                        <a href="<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
                        <div class="news-title">
                            <h1><a href="<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                            <div class="datetime"><span><time datetime="<?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?>"><?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?></time></span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

As you may notice, I'm working with Wordpress, and specifically with post images.

The case; The iteration runs 3 times, it is supposed to assign a class, and a left value, which will center the image.

But, the first iteration gets the height value of the second iteration, which in first place should be getting the width, of its own iteration. Weird huh.

I'll attach an image of what i'm trying to accomplish, maybe you have suggestions as to how to approach this dilemma.[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALOln.jpg)

Comment: can you add a sample HTML , e.g. browser rendered HTML from **DEVELOPERS CONSOLE**

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is no way that first iteration gets dimensions of second based on code shown

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for paying attention, I actually fixed by adding two lines only, specifying the current and rendered width and height of the image.

```js
// news section height calculator
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.news-picture').find('img').each(function () {
            
            var screenImage = $(this);
            var theImage = new Image();
            theImage.src = screenImage.attr("src");
            theImage.width = screenImage.attr("width");
            theImage.height = screenImage.attr("height");
            
// Get accurate measurements from that.
            var imageWidth = theImage.width;
            var imageHeight = theImage.height; 
            
            var $imgClass = (imageWidth / imageHeight);  
            var $imgPos = -((imageWidth - $(window).width()) / 2);
            console.log(imageWidth);    
            console.log($(window).width());  
            
            if ($imgClass >= 1) {
                $(this).addClass('wide').css("left" , $imgPos);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('tall');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.news-content {
background-color: #fff;
    margin: 25px auto;
}

.news-picture {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.news-picture:after {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10em #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10em #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10em #000 inset;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
}
.news-picture a {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
.wide {
    height: 100vw;
    width: auto;
    max-width: initial;
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
  
}
.news-title {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .news-title h1 {
    padding: 15px 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.news-title h1 a {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}
.datetime {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-container">
    <div class="news-content">
        <div class="news-picture">
            <a href="#"><img width="1298px" height="934px"  src="http://www.elliotjaystocks.com/assets/article_digest_1.png"></a>
            <div class="news-title">
                <h1><a href="#">First Iteration of the problem</a></h1>
                <div class="datetime"><span><time datetime="Sunday, October 23, 2016">Sunday, October 23, 2016</time></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-content">
        <div class="news-picture">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://guides.area17.com/app/uploads/sites/2/2015/10/05.08_AI_smart_guides-680x301.png"></a>
            <div class="news-title">
                <h1><a href="#">Second Iteration of the problem</a></h1>
                <div class="datetime"><span><time datetime="Sunday, October 23, 2016">Sunday, October 23, 2016</time></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="news-content">
        <div class="news-picture">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d6/05/49/d60549cbc19204feee1a672f71e43cee.jpg"></a>
            <div class="news-title">
                <h1><a href="#">Third Iteration of the problem</a></h1>
                <div class="datetime"><span><time datetime="Sunday, October 23, 2016">Sunday, October 23, 2016</time></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```